# Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 1093)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have moved CMS to a new server and I had an error on some pages:

> Unable to execute SELECT statement [SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT shop_products.id, shop_products.user_id, shop_products.route_id, shop_products.external_id, shop_products.active, shop_products.hit, shop_products.hot, shop_products.action, shop_products.archive, shop_products.brand_id, shop_products.category_id, shop_products.related_products, shop_products.old_price, shop_products.created, shop_products.updated, shop_products.views, shop_products.added_to_cart_count, shop_products.enable_comments, shop_products.tpl, shop_products_i18n.id, shop_products_i18n.locale, shop_products_i18n.name, shop_products_i18n.short_description, shop_products_i18n.full_description, shop_products_i18n.meta_title, shop_products_i18n.meta_description, shop_products_i18n.meta_keywords, IF(sum(shop_product_variants.stock) > 0, 1, 0) AS allstock FROM shop_products INNER JOIN shop_product_categories ON (shop_products.id=shop_product_categories.product_id) INNER JOIN shop_category ON (shop_products.category_id=shop_category.id) INNER JOIN shop_products_i18n ON (shop_products.id=shop_products_i18n.id AND shop_products_i18n.locale = :p1) INNER JOIN shop_product_variants ON (shop_products.id=shop_product_variants.product_id) LEFT JOIN shop_brands ON (shop_products.brand_id=shop_brands.id) WHERE shop_product_categories.category_id=:p2 AND shop_products.active=:p3 AND shop_products.archive=:p4 AND shop_category.active=:p5 GROUP BY shop_products.id ORDER BY allstock DESC,shop_product_variants.price DESC,shop_products.id DESC LIMIT 32]

I also fulfilled this request in PhpmyAdmin and got an errors of such a type:

> Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 1093)

Please tell me, why there is no such error on one server, but on another server it's displayed?

Comment: Which API are you using for accessing your database? And with which method call are you passing this SQL string as argument? The issue is with binding arguments.

Comment: No one is going to read that.  Format it properly, then maybe someone will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It complains about this join

`INNER JOIN shop_products_i18n ON (shop_products.id=shop_products_i18n.id AND shop_products_i18n.locale = :p1)`

make sure you're passing `p1` as an argument or join on a specific column instead of passing an argument?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved the problem. I set for debug = true in the CMS and saw the error mysql sql_mode = only_full_group_by. It was necessary only to add sql_mode = "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" in /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf